Determining The Domain of a Function With a Fractional Exponent
This is quite a rookie question, I realize, and I feel a little bit stupid for asking this, but I'm really confused.
Basically, is this $$\left(\sqrt[3]{x - 3}\right)^{2}$$
equal to this   $$\sqrt[3]{(x - 3)^2}$$ and equal to this $$\left(x - 3\right)^{\tfrac{2}{3}} \quad ?$$
Another related question is whether the domain of this function is limited to $x \geq 3$ or not because, for some reason, Geogebra says that the domain is not limited in any way, but WolframAlpha and Photomath both disagree. They believe that it is indeed limited to $x$ being $\geq 3$.
When putting something like $-8$ in these brackets instead of $x-3$, it seems to work just fine, and so to me, it would make sense for the domain not to be limited. But please just make a detailed explanation because I'm going nuts.

The cube root is defined for all real numbers. Consequently, $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Yes, that makes sense, but why is it so that when I give these exact prompts to Wolfram Alpha or to PhotoMath they both say that x ranges from 3 to infinity? It cost me hours

When you ask Wolfram Alpha to plot $(x-3)^{2/3}$ you see a graph with domain $x \ge 3$. The note from Wolfram says that is using the "principal root". In the complex plane every number has three cube roots. When looking for the cube root of a negative number the "principal root" isn't defined.
You can ask Wolfram Alpha to "use the real-valued root" instead. Then you see what you expect.
